# Get description of a Wikidata property?

Tags: wikidata, wikidata-api, pywikibot

How can we get a human readable property description of a Wikidata property (e.g.: [P31](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P31)) using pywikibot?

Comment: See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot/Wikidata for a general intro to using Pywikibot with Wikidata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `action=wbgetentities` for properties, just like you would for a normal item.

To get all human readable descriptions for `P31`:

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=P31
```

And to limit you results to one language (English):

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=P31&languages=en
```

Using pywikibot just for that task seems like a bit of overkill (pywikibot is a framework for building bots that do mass editing and the like, primarily on Wikipedia). I'm not sure it's even possible.
There are other, more lightweight frameworks, like [wikitools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikitools). With wikitools, you would do something like this:

```
from wikitools import Wiki, APIRequest

pid = "P31"
endpoint = "http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php"
username = "XXX"
password = "XXX"

site = Wiki(endpoint, username, password)
params = {'action':'wbgetentities', 'ids': pid}
request = APIRequest(site, params)
result = request.query()
print result["entities"][pid]["descriptions"]
```